# Delete rule for child entity in core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I am a bit confused by this message sent by Xcode:

**Setting the No Action Delete Rule on Passenger.taxi is an advanced setting [5]**

[image: Parent- and Child-Entity]

These are the specifications

1. When I delete a **Taxi** instance, it should also delete all its **Passenger** instances. *Current Delete Rule:* Cascade
2. When I delete a **Passenger** instance, it should just delete that particular instance. Even if it is the last **Passenger** instance of a **Taxi** instance. A Taxi can exist without Passengers (1:mc). *Current Delete Rule:* No Action

What delete rule do I need here to meet the requirements?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629481/xcode-consistency-error-setting-the-no-action-delete-rule-is-an-advanced-sett

Comment: That is a much more detailed explanation than the one I gave.

Comment: I skim-read that answer while trying to resolve the warning. But he explained it mainly for a 1:1 relationship. And the part about the m:n relationship is not clear to me (It does not explain my 2. spec).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the delete rule to nullify, which simply nils out the link.  "No Action" is a bit weird in that you can think of it as leaving a pointer that does not really exist I'm not sure if that's what it would really do).

Comment: Nullifying leads to the strange behavior - I can't fetch this entity anymore from data base! At least this occurs using MagicalRecord. The weird is to have the option which leads to 100% error occuring...the TS mentioned the a taxi CAN EXIST WITHOUT any passenger

Comment: Try dumping the full set of Taxi entities after the nil takes place.  it should still be there.  It's not impossible there's some kind of bug in MagicalRecord around this.

Comment: I've asked a question here, kindly ask you to take a look
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000640/magical-record-deleting-entity-issue