# Magical Record deleting entity issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I have a one-to-many relationship form Feedback to Questions in Feedback. The deletion rule is set to Nullify in Question and to Cascade in Feedback (so that when Feedback is deleted it deletes all its questions and when question is deleted it is pointer set to null in feedback.questions).

The problem is when I delete question (just a one question from many that exists in feedback) then I can't access feedback! Though the actual entry is really exist in DB (checked it with MesaSQLite)
The code looks like:

```
FeedbackQuestion * questionToDelete = [FeedbackQuestion findByQuestionId:[entryID integerValue]];
DLog(@"Deleting FeedbackQuestion with ID: %@", questionToDelete.questionID);
success = [questionToDelete MR_deleteEntity];
//success is 1 here
***
// Accessing the feedback which question was deleted
Feedback * feedback = [Feedback findByFeedbackId:feedbackId];
```

feedback is null here. WHY? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you save this deletion later?

Comment: can you post screenshots of your core data configuration from xcode?  specifically the attributes of the relationships.

Comment: On delete, it's hard coded in me to always return yes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hm, try maybe the following line after your "//success is 1 here" comment line:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

or, if you don't have the "shorthand-mode" enabled:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

Comment: Hey, this did the trick! your second method helped me to access feedback! Could you please explain me the thing-should I save a context every time I delete some entity? I thought that `MR_deleteEntity` method did all the stuff internally

Comment: Ah, believe me... i don't have a propper explanation for that! :) I was in a similar situation and just experimented with wat MR had to offer. After looking at the interfaces of MR i stumbled upon some of those "saveTo..." methods and started using them in order to persist my changes. I think this is entirely a core data thing and you have to understand how core data works in order to know if you need to explicitely persist something or not. MR is a realy nice framework but it doesn't relieve you from understaning core data - and i have still problems understaning core data in some areas!